# What causes the "already initialized constant" warning?

Tags: ruby, search, dir

What's wrong with my code? Is `FileNameArray` being reused?

f.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant FileNameArray

```
number = 0
while number < 99
  number = number + 1
  if number <= 9
    numbers = "000" + number.to_s
  elsif
    numbers = "00" + number.to_s
  end
  files = Dir.glob("/home/product/" + numbers + "/*/*.txt")
    files.each do |file_name|
    File.open(file_name,"r:utf-8").each do | txt |
      if txt =~ /http:\/\//
        if txt =~ /static.abc.com/ or txt =~ /static0[1-9].abc.com/
        elsif
        $find = txt
        FileNameArray = file_name.split('/')
        f = File.open("error.txt", 'a+')
        f.puts FileNameArray[8], txt , "\n"
        f.close
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: FileNameArray is a constant (because it is capitalized), and you are defining it in a loop.

Comment: @AlexD I am just starting out in Ruby myself and that tiny little bit of information that Capitalization is what creates a Constant is very helpful thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You might be a ruby beginner, I tried to rewrite the same code in ruby way...

```
(1..99).each do |number|
  Dir.glob("/home/product/" + ("%04d" % numbers) + "/*/*.txt").each do |file_name|
    File.open(file_name,"r:utf-8").each do | txt |
      next unless txt =~ /http:\/\//
      next if txt =~ /static.abc.com/ || txt =~ /static0[1-9].abc.com/        

      $find = txt
      file_name_array = file_name.split('/')
      f = File.open("error.txt", 'a+')
      f.puts file_name_array[8], txt , "\n"
      f.close      
    end
  end
end
```

Points to note down,

1. In ruby if you use a variable prefixed with `$` symbol, it is taken as a `global variable`. So use `$find`, only if it is required.
2. In ruby a `constant variable` starts with `capital letter`, usually we are **NOT** supposed to change a constant value. This might have caused the error in your program.
3. `(1..99)` is a literal used to create instance of [Range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html) class, which returns values from 1 to 99

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby variable name case matters. Local variables must start with a [lower case character](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope#Ruby_Local_Variables). Constants - with an upper case.

So, please try to rename `FileNameArray` to `fileNameArray`.

Also, `glob` takes advanced expressions that can save you one loop and a dozen of LOCs. In your case this expression should look something like:

`Dir.glob("/home/product/00[0-9][0-9]/*/*.txt")`

Comment: use Dir.glob("/home/product/00[0-9][0-9]/*/*.txt") is very slow that loop first,because Dig.glob will full scan the direct than pass filename to other process?

Comment: have you measured it? also, if there are not 99 folders in there but just 20 your for loop will still call glob 99 times - that's not right